# SnowFlake - Micropartition Extension

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-extension

We understand that snowflake stores the data in MicroPartition of each 16 MB ( Is that understanding correct?). Does the MicroPartition files are stored in .FDN file extension ? Is .FDN is snowflake proprietary ? what is the expansion of .FDN?

Also when i just insert one individual record, does snowflake create a new Micropartition file for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the full form of FDN is Flocon De Neige which is snowflake in French. This is a proprietary format. To add to what Mike said, since SNOWFLAKE is immutable and every insert will create a new partition, it is not advisable to insert records one at a time in SNOWFLAKE, this is by design. Inserting one record versus 100,000 records will roughly take the same amount of time. It is therefore recommended to do a batch insert in SNOWFLAKE.Understanding partitioning is also crucial for optimizing your queries.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please accept the answer that solves your query

Answer (score 0):

Roughly 16MB in file size is correct.  And your last question is yes (since files stored on blob storage are immutable).  The new file may be a consolidation of that one record plus other records from another micropartition, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I didn't understand the point - "The new file may be a consolidation of that one record plus other records from another micropartition"                                                                                              Above point might be true if i do clustering. If not when i insert one singe record, it should create single partition with only one record right?

Comment: If you have a 1 record micropartition and then you insert a new record in that table, Snowflake may take the 1 record micropartition and the new record and create a 2-record micropartition.  There is some intelligence to the backend on when and when not to do that.